# Is shutting off the water supply line to replace a refrigerator water filter normal?

Tags: water, refrigerator

I'm looking into purchasing a new refrigerator. A particular Samsung model looks like a potential but I noticed an odd instruction in its manual. Regarding replacing its water filter, the first step is to shut off the water supply line.

Is this a standard requirement? Is the expectation that I shut off water coming into my house? (I don't want to have to pull the fridge out every time the filter needs changing.) I ask since with my current refrigerator, I don't need to shut off the water supply line to change a water filter.

Comment: Where is the water filter located?

Comment: I have a 8 yr old Samsung and have replaced the filter at least 8 times without turning off the supply. The first few times I pulled the fridge out from the wall so I could get to the valve quickly , but now I just twist out the old and twist in the new ( with fingers crossed) . Our filter is between the vegetable drawers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is have a local shut off . My state requires a valve box in the wall access behind the fridge. If you have this on the supply to the fridge it meets the requirements. With this normally ball valve turned 90 degrees and a glass of water tried to fill the pressure will be gone in 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Samsung refrigerator and have replaced the filter many times without shutting of the water supply.  If you read the instructions in the manual very carefully you will see that even though they say to shut off the water supply at the beginning, they treat this instruction as an option, not a requirement. The very last instruction in my manual says to turn back the water if you turned it off implying that it is not necessary.